# When search Django rest framework instead of showing all records, I want only first record

Tags: django, api, rest, frameworks

I have setup django rest framework which is working fine. I can see list of my record or when search it also working.  I want to make a change that if I do search it only give me first record instead of all searched record.  Here is the example of my code which i tried but not working.  Please guide.  Thanks

class PhoneNumberModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = PhoneNumbers.objects.all()
serializer_class = PhoneNumbersSerializer
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
search_fields = ['area_code']
```

I want to make a change that if I do search it only give me first record instead of all searched record.  Here is the example of my code which i tried but not working.  Please guide.  Thanks

class PhoneNumberModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = PhoneNumbers.objects.all()
serializer_class = PhoneNumbersSerializer
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
search_fields = ['area_code']

def get(self):
    queryset = super().get()
    area_code = self.request.query_params.get('area_code')
    if area_code:
        try:
            queryset = queryset.filter(area_code=area_code)[0:1]
        except IndexError:
            queryset = PhoneNumbers.objects.none()
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering instead of search and try to avoid overriding get methods as you can.

try something like this

```
from rest_framework import filters

class PhoneNumberModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PhoneNumbers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhoneNumbersSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
       
        page_size = self.get_paginate_by(request)
        if not page_size:
            return None

        # Check if search query is provided
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)
        if search_query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(area_code=search_query)[:1]

        return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

I hope this help..